# Querying image differences due to storing(saving) data in Mat* variables in C++ & openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, opencv-mat

I'm a beginner in C++. The code I wrote in two different ways has different results. I think it's due to pointers, but I don't know why. Inside the return_image function, the image is fine, but outside the function, when received by pointer, the image is broken. The images of return_image2 function are all good.
I've attached an OK image and an NG image.

PS C:\opencv\pjt> g++ e.cpp -o e.exe -I"c:\opencv\build\install\include" -L"c:\opencv\build\install\x64\mingw\lib" -L"c:\opencv\build\install\x64\mingw\bin" -lopencv_core470 -lopencv_highgui470 -lopencv_imgproc470 -lopencv_imgcodecs470
PS C:\opencv\pjt> ./e

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp> // Mat
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> // rectangle
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void return_image(int x, int y, Mat* result)
{
    Mat img=Mat (x, y, CV_8UC3);

    int k=0;
    unsigned char grid_color[x*y*3];
    unsigned char *grid_color_ptr=&grid_color[0];

    for (int i=0;i<x;i++) for(int j=0;j<y;j++) {
     grid_color[k]=j; // B
     k++;
     grid_color[k]=j; // G
     k++;
     grid_color[k]=j; // R
     k++;
     }

    ////////////////////////////
    img.data=grid_color_ptr;
    ////////////////////////////

    rectangle(img, Rect(Point(0, 0), Point(img.cols, img.rows)), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 4, 0);
    *result=img;

    imshow("original image", *result); // Image OK
    moveWindow("original image",0,0);
}

void return_image2(int x, int y, Mat* result)
{
    Mat img=Mat (x, y, CV_8UC3);

    int k=0;

    ////////////////////////////
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++) for(int j=0;j<y;j++) {
     img.data[k]=j; // B
     k++;
     img.data[k]=j; // G
     k++;
     img.data[k]=j; // R
     k++;
     }
    ////////////////////////////

    rectangle(img, Rect(Point(0, 0), Point(img.cols, img.rows)), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 4, 0);
    *result=img;
    imshow("original image2", *result); // Image OK
    moveWindow("original image2",0,175);
}

main() {

    Mat img;
    return_image(150,255,&img);
    imshow("returned image", img); // Image NG
    moveWindow("returned image",255,0);

    Mat img2;
    return_image2(150,255,&img2);
    imshow("returned image2", img2); // Image OK
    moveWindow("returned image2",255,175);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkEGw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In `return_image`, your `grid_color` array is going out of scope at the end of the function, though you are using a pointer to it as your data buffer for `img`.

This will allow `img` to point at the proper data within the scope of the function. But once the function returns and the memory from the local scope is freed, `img` now holds an invalid pointer to memory that was freed.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

void add1(int a,int b,int *r)
{
    *r=b+a;
}

void add2(int a,int b,int *r)
{
    int i=a+b;
    int *j;
    j=&i;
    r=j;
}

This case also gives me an error similar to my question.